# Multithreaded system calls in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, system, system-calls, sidekiq

I have a system that send some processing to queues using sidekiq. These processes consist on doing system calls to programs that manipulate images. I'm having a very bad performance for this program. When I 'top' my system, almost all cpu is consumed by ruby, and just a few CPU by the image software.

I've tried to test with 5, 10, 20, 30 workers. Adding more workers does not improve the processing performance (with high values it is even worse).

My worker is something like this:

```
def perform(file)
    command = "convert -strip -resize 580x580 -quality 90 -sampling-factor 4:2:0 -interlace Plane #{file} #{file}.main"
    `#{command}`
end
```

Is there any way to improve multithreaded system calls in Ruby?

Comment: What makes you think Resque is multithreaded?

Comment: @DanielCukier Resque aint multithread it use `fork` internally

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, unfortunately, Resque's core design. Because it uses a forking worker model, and because Ruby 1.9 is not CoW-friendly, the first GC invocation in each subprocess results in a full copy of that entire process's memory space. This is slow.

Many people have moved to [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) as an alternative specifically because of this problem. A thread is much cheaper than a fork under Ruby 1.9, and should result in significantly improved performance.

That said, once Ruby 2.0 ships with a CoW-friendly memory GC model, Resque should be significantly more competitive. But, that won't happen for a couple of quarters, at least.

Comment: Actually, I made a confusion: I'm already using sidekiq :-) and still got performance issues

Comment: "CoW" meaning "Copy on Write", not "Cluster of Workstations", right?